# Apache Flink and event sequencing

Tags: java, apache-flink

I am new to Apache Flink and am trying to organize data from IoT devices that monitor devices scanning for Wifi. A typical event will look like:

{ NodeId, Device MAC address, Time, Type }

I want to be able to look at the previous event for a MAC address and if the current event time is less than a specified interval from the last event for that MAC address e.g 60 seconds, I want to update a running total of events for that MAC. If, however, the interval time has passed I want the aggregated event to be written to a database. The aggregated event would look something like:

{ NodeId, MAC address, Last Event Time, Total Events, Date, Hour }

To further complicate things, I want to keep hourly and daily running totals for each NodeId keeping a running total for all MAC address events per Node and once the relevant period is completed, to output to a database.

I've looked through the documentation but am struggling a little bit to understand the pieces I need to use to accomplish this task.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This sounds like a problem of generating aggregates for [session](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.2/dev/windows.html#session-windows) windows.

You can do sth like:

```
stream.keyBy(new KeySelector<Event, Integer>() {
    @Override
    public Integer getKey(Event value) throws Exception {
        return value.nodeId;
    }
}).window(EventTimeSessionWindows.withGap(Time.seconds(60)))
  .apply(new ReduceFunction<LogRow>(), new WindowFunction<LogRow, Object, Integer, TimeWindow>())
```